# send button EventListener if else

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, event-handling

I have a feedback form with 3 clickable images for user satisfaction rating:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsUkd.png

Fairly new to javascript. When I run the .addeventListener on my script it works on the first if statement, and if I remove elses it alternates on which if runs.
below is the html and javascript:

```
 <div id="panel" class="panel-container">
      <strong>How satisfied are you with our customer support performance?</strong>
      <div class="ratings-container">
        <div class="rating" id="sad">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/187/187150.svg" alt=""/>
          <small>Unhappy</small>
        </div>
        <div class="rating" id="meh">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/187/187136.svg" alt=""/>
          <small>Neutral</small>
        </div>
        <div class="rating active" id="happy">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/187/187133.svg" alt=""/>
          <small>Satisfied</small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn" id="send">Send review</button>
    </div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
const ratingsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");
const sendBtn = document.querySelector("#send");
const panel = document.querySelector("#panel");
const sad = document.querySelector("#sad");
const meh = document.querySelector("#meh");
const happy = document.querySelector("#happy");



ratingsEl.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ratingsEl.forEach((innerEl) => {
      innerEl.classList.remove("active");
    });

    el.classList.add("active");
  });
});

sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(sad){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>sad</p>
    `;
    }

     else if(meh){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>meh</p>
    `;
    }
     else if(happy){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>feedack for this</p>
    `;
    }
});
```

I have tried using the :

```
ev.currentTarget.id == "myId"
```

function in my if blocks
and tried a different event listener for each block, but did not work.

i thought of using the

```
button.tagName === "myId"
```

statement at some point in my if, but i am using one button for all 3.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the code you have written:

```
if (sad) {
    // ...
}
else if (meh) {
    // ...
}
else if (happy) {
    // ...
}
```

`sad`, `meh` and `happy` all evalutes to `true` when used as a condition. Since the condition of the first if evalutes to `true`, only that block runs everytime.

You should check which element among the `sad`, `meh` and `happy` has the `active` class.

Please use the following code instead

```
sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(sad.classList.contains("active")){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>sad</p>
    `;
    }

    else if(meh.classList.contains("active")){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>meh</p>
    `;
    }

    else if(happy.classList.contains("active")){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>feedack for this</p>
    `;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the active review in a global variable and update it when a new review is selected and update that when the button is clicked.

Doing so you don't have to individually select all the elements and check which one has the `active` class.

```js
const ratingsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");
const sendBtn = document.querySelector("#send");
const panel = document.querySelector("#panel");

let review = "happy";

ratingsEl.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    ratingsEl.forEach((innerEl) => {
      innerEl.classList.remove("active");
    });
    el.classList.add("active");
    review = el.id;
  });
});

sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  panel.innerHTML = `<p>${review}</p>`;
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
}

.rating {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.rating small {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating.active small{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel" class="panel-container">
  <strong>How satisfied are you with our customer support performance?</strong>
  <div class="ratings-container">
    <div class="rating" id="sad">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/187/187150.svg" alt="" />
      <small>Unhappy</small>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" id="meh">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/187/187136.svg" alt="" />
      <small>Neutral</small>
    </div>
    <div class="rating active" id="happy">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/187/187133.svg" alt="" />
      <small>Satisfied</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="send">Send review</button>
</div>
```

Or, you can individually check which element has the `active` class in it.

Also, I would suggest avoid setting content using `innerHTML`, instead create an element and append it.

```
sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  panel.innerHTML = "";
  const usrReview = document.createElement("p");
  usrReview.innerText = review;
  panel.appendChild(usrReview);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above.
You can also use the toggle if all you want to do is add and remove it.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmqdhgnj/3/

```
const ratingsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");
const sendBtn = document.querySelector("#send");
const panel = document.querySelector("#panel");
const sad = document.querySelector("#sad");
const meh = document.querySelector("#meh");
const happy = document.querySelector("#happy");

ratingsEl.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    toggle(el,"active");
  });
});

function toggle(el, className) {
        el.classList.toggle(className);
}

sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(sad.className, meh.className, happy.className)
    if(sad.className.includes("active")){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>sad</p>
    `;
    }

     if(meh.className.includes("active")){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>meh</p>
    `;
    }
    if(happy.className.includes("active")){
        panel.innerHTML = `
        <p>feedack for this</p>
    `;
    }
});
```